# C programming : Array

Tags: c, arrays

My problem: Input the string1 and split string1 into string a containing even number and string b containing odd number.

ex: array: 4 3 1 2 6 8

array a: 2 4 6 8
array b: 1 3

when i ran this code, it had problem. Can you help me find the mistakes?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void problem(int a[100], int n);
void bubblesort(int a[100], int n);
void print_array(int a[100], int n);

int main()
{
    int b[100],c[100],evenlen=0,oddlen=0,a[100], n;
    printf("Input n: "); scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Input array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((a[i] % 2) == 0)
        {
            a[i] = b[evenlen];
            evenlen++;
        }
        else
        {
            a[i] = c[oddlen];
            oddlen++;
        }
    }
    bubblesort(b, evenlen);
    bubblesort(c, oddlen);
    printf("The even array : "); print_array(b, evenlen);
    printf("\nThe odd array : "); print_array(c, oddlen);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void bubblesort(int a[100], int n)
{
    int hold;
    for (int pass = 0; pass < n;pass++)
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
        if (a[i]>a[i + 1])
          {
           hold = a[i];
           a[i] = a[i + 1];
           a[i + 1] = hold;
          }
        }
}

void print_array(int a[100], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: `when i ran this code, it had problem`...what problem?

Comment: looks that `bubblesort()` does not sort your array. Google for bubble sort algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

This loop is troublesome:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if ((a[i] % 2) == 0)
    {
        a[i] = b[evenlen];
        evenlen++;
    }
    else
    {
        a[i] = c[oddlen];
        oddlen++;
    }
}
```

It's troublesome because you assign *to* the entries in the `a` array from the (*uninitialized*) `b` and `c` arrays.

Because the `b` and `c` arrays are not initialized their contents is *indeterminate* and reading from them leads to *undefined behavior*.

I think you meant to do the opposite assignments, assign *to* the `b` and `c` arrays from `a`.

Answer (score 2):

you are doing assigning in wrong way

change this line

```
a[i] = b[evenlen]; // wrong line
```

to

```
b[evenlen] = a[i] ;
```

And

```
a[i] = c[oddlen];   // wrong line
```

To

```
c[oddlen] = a[i];
```